# How do I find the hexidecimal hash string of an element in Appium iOS?

Tags: scroll, appium, webdriver-io

I am currently trying to figure out how to tell appium to scroll a specific element in an app in iOS simulator. I'm following [this documentation](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures.md)

In the arguments available for the mobile: scroll functionality, it states the following:

> *element: The internal element identifier (as hexadecimal hash string) to scroll on. Application element will be used if this argument is not
>   set*

I can't find any documentation on how to find or identify the hexadecimal hash string of an element in Appium. Any recommendation of how I can accomplish this? I am using the webdriver.io framework with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy. You just need to call `.getId()` to get hexadecimal id of the element.